# Как передать массив значений из формы имеющей цикл в POST

Tags: php, массивы, post, циклы, form

Есть форма,внутри цикл, перебирающий поля из таблицы бд. При передаче методом post в обработчик, в $_POST попадает только последний товар таблицы. Как передать все товары из таблицы,которые перебирает foreach?

вот форма-

```
           <?php foreach ($about_skills as $key => $value): ?>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                     <!--    Context Classes  -->
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <form action="/admin/about" method="post">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <input type="text" name="skill_name" class="skill_name_input" value="<?php echo $key?>">
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">                                  
                                        <tbody>
                                           <?php foreach($value as $about_skill => $this_skill): ?>


                                                    <tr>

                                                        <td>
                                                        <input type="text" name="about_name" class="about_name_input" value="<?php echo $this_skill['about_name']?>">

                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <input type="number" name="about_val" class="input_val" value="<?php echo $this_skill['about_val']?>"> 

                                                        </td>

                                                    </tr>


                                            <?php endforeach ; ?>

                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                                <input type="submit" name="skills_update" class="btn btn-warning about_change" value="upd">
                        </div>
                        </form>  
                    </div>

                    <!--  end  Context Classes  -->
                </div>
            <?php endforeach ; ?>
```

вот обработчик-

```
if (isset($_POST['skills_update'])) {

    var_dump($_POST);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Короче решил задачу просто. В инпутах, которые что-то должны передавать в $_POST, в name добавил - [].

```
<input type="text" name="about_name[]" class="about_name_input" value="<?php echo $this_skill['about_name']?>">
```

Comment: Плохая практика... Очень... Для правильного решения  - воспользуйтесь `filter_input`, а для массивов, воспользуйтесь правильной константой для входных данных.

Comment: почему плохая? ведь в value находится массив,вот я и ставлю []

Comment: Плохая практика использовать супер глобальный массив `$_POST`.